# Сумма сумм MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Как посчитать сумму сумм в mysql? Т.е у меня есть запрос

```
 `SELECT SUM(Prstoim)/COUNT(*), Yeardoc FROM table.dbf Where country IN ('Россия', 'Германия', 'Италия', 'Нидерланды', 'Япония')   Group BY yeardoc INTO cursor test`
```

Он считает среднюю суммарную стоимость приборов по странам по годам. Но он считает таким образом, что если например в России суммарная стоимость 1000 и 20 приборов, а в Германии суммарная стоимость 2000 и 13 приборов, то он сначала считает суммарные стоимости в обоих странах (3000) и суммарное кол-во приборов(33) и после находит среднюю стоимость. А как можно найти сумму сумм, т.е чтобы сначала он посчитал в России, т.е 1000/20, после в германии 3000/13 и сложил две суммы?

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо использовать CTE. (заранее извиняюсь, если немного в синтаксе напутал, в основном имею дело с mssql)

```
WITH testCTE (country, av, yeardoc) as 
(SELECT 
    country,
    SUM(Prstoim)/COUNT(*) as av, 
    Yeardoc 
FROM table.dbf 
Where country IN ('Россия', 'Германия', 'Италия', 'Нидерланды', 'Япония')   
Group BY yeardoc, country)

SELECT 
    SUM(av)
FROM testCTE
```

Сначала в CTE вы получаете набор данных, где для каждой страны и года посчитано значение `SUM(Prstoim)/COUNT(*)`, а затем получаете общую сумму, суммируя данные из предварительного набора.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, а не могли бы вы перевести на mysql? А то сходу выдает ошибку, что переменная country не найдена

Comment: `Where country IN ('Россия', 'Германия', 'Италия', 'Нидерланды', 'Япония')`  а в данном случае у вас `country`    это что, не поле в таблице?

Comment: все верно, поле в таблице, ошибка на строке WITH testCTE (country, av, yeardoc) as , я использую visual foxpro, если что

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `WITH testCTE (country, av, yeardoc) as ` просто `WITH testCTE as (...`

Comment: в таком случае пишет TESTCTE not found

Comment: @LightSight Не мучайтесь. У Вас старая (5+) версия MySQL, которая даже не подозревает о существовании CTE. Переместите запрос из CTE в секцию FROM (замените `WITH testCTE AS (запрос) SELECT ... FROM testCTE ...` на `SELECT ... FROM (запрос) testCTE ...`).

Comment: *а затем получаете общую сумму, суммируя данные из предварительного набора* Ему как бы среднее надо, а не сумму. Так что AVG().

Comment: А в конце вопроса стоит именно "сложить две суммы")